# hashset to database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have 2 hashsets:

```
Private workMembers As New HashSet(Of String)()
Private clientMembers As New HashSet(Of String)()
```

These hashsets are either added to or removed from depending on what button the user presses(add or remove).

I need to delete a row from my MSSQL database if a member is removed and insert a row if a member is added.

I have 2 questions:

Is there a way to update my database from what is left in the hashsets?

Would I need to design two separate functions to handle both of these?

Thanks!

Comment: Which database product are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: You can essentially do a diff, but how often are you talking you want to do that?  You are in a stateless environment, so how are you persisting the hashsets?